# Laravel update column key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I am trying to remove the unique key from `complaint_number` column with migration because my app is on production and can't figure it up....

this is what I have right now:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('complaints', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('complaint_number', 7)->unique();
            $table->string('address');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that migration have already been run, so what you need to do is to create a new migration and in that drop the unique index.

```
php artisan migrate:make drop_complaint_number_unique_index
```

And this for the `up` method:

```
Schema::table('complaint', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropIndex('complaints_complaint_number_unique');
}
```

And this for the `down` method (re-add the unique index):

```
Schema::table('complaint', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unique(['complaint_number']);
}
```